# How to use BigQuery Slots

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi,there.

Recently,I want to run a query in bigquery web UI by using "group by" over some tables(tables' name suits xxx_mst_yyyymmdd).The rows will be over 10 million. Unhappily,the query failed with this error:

**Query Failed
Error: Resources exceeded during query execution.**

I did some improvements with my query language,the error may not happen for this time.But with the increasement of my data, the Error will also appear in the future.So I checked the latest release of Bigquery,maybe there two ways to solve this:

1.After 2016/01/01,Bigquery will change the Query pricing tiers to satisfy the "High Compute Tiers" so that the "resourcesExceeded error" will not happen again.

2.BigQuery Slots.
  I checked some documents in Google and didn't find a way on how to use BigQuery Slots.Is there any sample or usecase of BigQuery Slots?Or I have to contact with BigQuery Team to open the function?

Hope someone can help me to answer this question,thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of points:

1. I'm surprised that a GROUP BY with a cardinality of 10M failed with resources exceeded. Can you provide a job id of the failed query so we can investigate? You mention that you're concerned about hitting these errors more often as your data size increases; you should likely be able to increase your data size by a few more orders of magnitude without seeing this; likely you've encountered either a bug or something was strange with either your query or your data.
2. "High Compute Tiers" won't necessarily get rid of resourcesExceeded. For the most part, resourcesExceeded means that BigQuery ran into memory limitations; high compute tiers only address CPU usage. (and note, they haven't been enabled yet).
3. BigQuery slots enable you to process data faster and with more reliable performance. For the most part, they also wouldn't help prevent resourcesExceeded errors.
4. There is currently (as of Nov 5) a bug where you may need to provide an EACH keyword with a GROUP BY. Recent changes should enable BigQuery to automatically select the execution strategy, so EACH shouldn't be needed, but there are a couple of cases where it doesn't pick the right one. When in doubt, add an EACH to your JOIN and GROUP BY operations.

Comment: Jordan Tigani,thanks for your suggestions,as you asked "what the job id is",since there some business secrets in that project,so I provided the SQL and Job Id in Google SupportCenter,and if there any news for it,I will update this ticket.

Comment: as a brief view of my SQL:

SELECT COUNT(*) AS ct, A, B, C FROM
(SELECT A, B, C FROM [dataset.a]
)
GROUP BY A, B, C
HAVING ct > 1

Or like this:

SELECT COUNT(*) AS ct, A, B, C  FROM [dataset.a]
GROUP BY A, B, C
HAVING ct > 1

the row number of dataset.a is about 11,000,000.

Comment: update:
SELECT COUNT() AS ct, A, B, C FROM (SELECT A, B, C FROM [dataset.a] ) GROUP BY A, B, C HAVING ct > 1 → fail.

SELECT COUNT() AS ct, A, B, C FROM (SELECT A, B, C FROM [dataset.a] ) GROUP EACH BY A, B, C HAVING ct > 1 → success.


This seems like EACH is also needed.

Comment: I've updated my response to include the suggestion to add EACH. As I mentioned, this is a bug that we're actively working on fixing.

Answer (score 1):

To get your project eligible for using slots you need to contact support.